# remove the builtin tool tip on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a tool tip using html, jquery, and css. The Tool tip uses the title attribute in order to show its contents.

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Hello">Hover Me</a>
```

When I hover the link I see the tool tip and its working fine. The problem is that I also see the built in html tool tip. Is there any way to disable that html tool tip ? OR is there any other attribute that I can use to solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Remove the title attribute on hover, and then add it back in on mouseout.

Comment: @BenM - You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also define an arbitrary attribute that you target for your purpose.
This is easy to do using JQuery.

ex: `<a href="#" class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Hello">Hover Me</a>`

Comment: You should at least use standards-compliant custom attributes. `data-tooltip` would have been acceptable.

Comment: I agree. Updated my answer

Comment: Thats better! It is not as accessible as the native `title` attribute, but still better than nothing.

Comment: how do I select the data-tooltip ? like this ? this.data("tooltip") ?

Comment: @MaxPain - Yes, exactly. Just make sure that `this` is a jQuery object, and not a native DOM node. You may need to write this: `$(this).data('tooltip')`

Comment: retrieve it like this: $("#element").attr("data-tooltip")

Comment: Set it like this: $("#element").attr("data-tooltip","some value")

Answer (score 2):

To maintain SEO and so forth, I'd just remove the `title` attribute temporarily, and then add it back in; something like this:

```
$('element').hover(function() {
    var title = $(this).prop('title');  
    $(this).data('orig-title', title).prop('title', '');
}, function() {  
    $(this).prop('title', $(this).data('orig-title'));
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.prop()` be `.attr()`, if the markup contains a `title` attribute?